# Using try in "if" row python

Tags: python, if-statement

I can't figure out by myself how to do this.

I want to add "try" statement in row of "if" statements, but just on first one, I tried this, but it's not working:

```
try:
   if something1 == something22:
except:
     break
if something2 == something3: #this line must not be called if first if inside try is not True
   if something4234 == something65543:
       #and so on
```

To sum up, I want to check if something1 == something22 and if it's true, then code will continue, if it's false, it will stop...

EDIT:

Here's better explanation:

http://pastebin.com/MyMr3Byr

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What's a "`try` loop"? Please work on improving the clarity of the question.

Comment: @devnull How could I fix indentation? I'll edit my question to make it more clear.

Comment: @NPE I'm sorry, statement*. Edited.

Comment: @user3393616 why would you expect the comparison to give you an error?

Comment: @jonrsharpe but it actually gives me error http://pastebin.com/4YiwRKj7

Comment: @user3393616 The comparison is not raising an exception. Your code is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @juanchopanza how can I fix it?

Comment: @user3393616 have you *read* the error message? You can't fix a `SyntaxError` with `try`. Fix your indentation; white space is important in python. Each level should be four spaces deeper than the last.

Comment: I suggest going through the first chapters of an introductory python book. It will be more effective than randomly typing code and then asking why it doesn't work.

Comment: @jonrsharpe I know that, but if I indent if statement for four spaces, it will do it inside except, and I don't want it... I want to to do everything below (below try statement) only if something1 == something22...

Comment: @user3393616 then use `else`, per my answer; that is the block that runs if there isn't an exception in the `try`.

Comment: @user3393616 *stop posting links to pastebin*. Edit your question to include the appropriate code, correctly formatted, and a precise description of what you are trying to achieve and what exactly is going wrong. Please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do:

```
try:
    if this or that or the_other:
except:
```

You get an error because Python expects an indented block after the `if` statement, as you would normally have:

```
if it_works:
    print("yay") # indented block
```

Also, you can't `break` if you aren't already in a loop. In a loop, `break` skips to the end of the loop, but if you aren't in a loop where is the code supposed to go?

If the comparison sometimes fails, you could do:

```
try:
    if something1.attr != something2.attr:
        pass # do nothing if they don't match
except AttributeError: # guard against specific error
    pass # do nothing if the comparison fails
else:
    # continue otherwise
    ...
```

The `else` block here will only run if:

1. The comparison is made without error; and
2. The comparison evaluates to `True`.

If something completely unexpected happens (i.e. not an `AttributeError`), that error will still get passed up the stack so we find out about it.

Comment: I can't use that because something1 and something22 sometimes returns errors. I'm coding minecraft (bukkit) plugin in python, and when I use i.e. event.getBlock().getType == event.getPlayer().getBlock().getType() it spitts errors because not every block has type...

Comment: Ok, edited. Can any of those comparisons fail, then? Or just the first one? This would be easier if you provided code that better represented what you were actually doing and the specific error messages (*here*, not on pastebin).

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MyMr3Byr I hope it's better explained.

Comment: @user3393616 Update your question; stop posting links to pastebin.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to execute an IF statement and want to exit the snippet of code if something goes wrong:

```
try:
    if something1 == something2:
        # your code goes here
        pass
except:
    write("Somting wong in ze cod")
    write("continuing the program...")
```

you don't need a break statement after excpet... you usually use it to break while or for loops. Based on your requirements I would recommend to skip the try clause and simply use

```
if statement1==statement2:
    #code goes here
    pass
```

unless you forebode that an error might occur when evaluating the if or #code goes here statements

Answer (score 0):

The canonical way to do your thing is by means of a nested `if`.

```
if something1 == something22:
    if something2 == something3:
        if something4234 == something65543:
            do_something()
```

Just forget about `try`/`catch` to sort out of a an `if`, unless you explicitly want to `raise` some exception:

```
if something1 != something22:
    raise MyException
```

Or unless some of the comparisons is liable to result in an exception, in which case just put the `try`/`catch` outside the whole thing:

```
try:
    if something1 == something22:
        if something2 == something3:
            if something4234 == something65543:
                do_something()
catch:
    handle_exception()
```

Comment: I can't use that because something1 and something22 sometimes returns errors. I'm coding minecraft (bukkit) plugin in python, and when I use i.e. event.getBlock().getType == event.getPlayer().getBlock().getType() it spitts errors because not every block has type...

Comment: Then *do* enclose the whole `if` structure in a `try/catch`.

Comment: Fact is that I don't want to raise exception! Because it's normal error and it spams my console, I don't want it to appear, that's why I want to use try/except..

Comment: I edited my answer... Look at the final part! :)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/MyMr3Byr Can you please take a look into this, I think I explained it better here...